# Can't create Flow

Tags: power-automate

I already tried [asking](http://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Can-t-create-UI-Flow/td-p/398341) this in the official Flow forum, and I'm hoping to get help here.

I signed up for a [Community Plan](http://powerapps.microsoft.com/communityplan). I'm following the [instructions](http://learn.microsoft.com/flow/ui-flows/create-desktop) to create a UI Flow. I've installed [UI Flows](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/ui-flows/setup#install-ui-flows-on-your-device), but not the [data gateway](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/ui-flows/setup#install-the-on-premises-data-gateway).

I'm getting an error message saying "You don't have any CDS subscription yet. To create UI flows (preview) automations, please first choose a plan that's right for you." How can I fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately that forum is better than Stack Overflow for this kind of thing because it's really a question that Microsoft employees would have to answer, possibly by looking at your account details. I would recommend filing a ticket in the Office 365 Admin Center or having your Office 365 Global Admin (if you don't have access to the Admin Center) file a ticket with Microsoft Support, if you aren't getting any luck on the Flow forums.

Comment: I tried, but I'm getting an error message saying "Premium Plan Required".

Answer (score 0):

I found a [solution](http://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Can-t-create-UI-Flow/m-p/415750/highlight/true#M47852).

> I started reading the documentation from the beginning. I found a line that says "If you haven't used the Common Data Service before, open the Entities tab of powerapps.com, and then click or tap Create my database." After doing this, the error message went away.